# Graphframes/Graphx connected components skipping numbers

Tags: python, apache-spark, spark-graphx, connected-components, graphframes

I'm using the Spark Graphframes library to create an identity resolution system. I have been able to use spark to find matches. My plan was to use a graph to find transient links between people and assign a single id to them for further analysis etc.

I used the following data (from the public febrl database):

vertex data sample:

```
+----------+--------+-------------+-------------------+--------------------+----------------+--------+-----+-------------+----------+---+-----+
|given_name| surname|street_number|          address_1|           address_2|          suburb|postcode|state|date_of_birth|soc_sec_id| id|block|
+----------+--------+-------------+-------------------+--------------------+----------------+--------+-----+-------------+----------+---+-----+
|  michaela| neumann|            8|     stanley street|               miami|   winston hills|    4223|  nsw|     19151111|   5304218|  0| mneu|
|  courtney| painter|           12|  pinkerton circuit|          bega flats|       richlands|    4560|  vic|     19161214|   4066625|  1| cpai|
|   charles|   green|           38|salkauskas crescent|                kela|           dapto|    4566|  nsw|     19480930|   4365168|  2| cgre|
|   vanessa|    parr|          905|     macquoid place|   broadbridge manor|   south grafton|    2135|   sa|     19951119|   9239102|  3| vpar|
|   mikayla|malloney|           37|      randwick road|             avalind|hoppers crossing|    4552|  vic|     19860208|   7207688|  4| mmal|
|     blake|   howie|            1|     cutlack street|belmont park belt...|        budgewoi|    6017|  vic|     19250301|   5180548|  5| bhow|
| blakeston| broadby|           53|     traeger street|   valley of springs|      north ward|    3083|  qld|     19120907|   4308555|  7| bbro|
|    edward| denholm|           10|        corin place|           gold tyne|       clayfield|    4221|  vic|     19660306|   7119771|  9| eden|
|   charlie|alderson|          266|hawkesbury crescent|deergarden caravn...|           cooma|    4128|  vic|     19440908|   1256748| 10| cald|
|     molly|   roche|           59|willoughby crescent|        donna valley|         carrara|    4825|  nsw|     19200712|   1847058| 11| mroc|
+----------+--------+-------------+-------------------+--------------------+----------------+--------+-----+-------------+----------+---+-----+
```

Edge data sample:

```
+---+-----+-----+
|src|  dst|match|
+---+-----+-----+
|  0|10000|    1|
|  1|17750|    1|
|  1|10001|    1|
|  1| 7750|    1|
|  2|19656|    1|
|  2|10002|    1|
|  2| 9656|    1|
|  3|19119|    1|
|  3|10003|    1|
|  3| 9119|    1|
+---+-----+-----+
```

created graph:

```
g = GraphFrame(vertix_data, edge_data)
```

used connected components:

```
connected = g.connectedComponents(algorithm='graphframes')
```

which results in:

```
+----------+--------+-------------+-------------------+--------------------+----------------+--------+-----+-------------+----------+---+-----+---------+
|given_name| surname|street_number|          address_1|           address_2|          suburb|postcode|state|date_of_birth|soc_sec_id| id|block|component|
+----------+--------+-------------+-------------------+--------------------+----------------+--------+-----+-------------+----------+---+-----+---------+
|  michaela| neumann|            8|     stanley street|               miami|   winston hills|    4223|  nsw|     19151111|   5304218|  0| mneu|        0|
|  courtney| painter|           12|  pinkerton circuit|          bega flats|       richlands|    4560|  vic|     19161214|   4066625|  1| cpai|        1|
|   charles|   green|           38|salkauskas crescent|                kela|           dapto|    4566|  nsw|     19480930|   4365168|  2| cgre|        2|
|   vanessa|    parr|          905|     macquoid place|   broadbridge manor|   south grafton|    2135|   sa|     19951119|   9239102|  3| vpar|        3|
|   mikayla|malloney|           37|      randwick road|             avalind|hoppers crossing|    4552|  vic|     19860208|   7207688|  4| mmal|        4|
|     blake|   howie|            1|     cutlack street|belmont park belt...|        budgewoi|    6017|  vic|     19250301|   5180548|  5| bhow|        5|
| blakeston| broadby|           53|     traeger street|   valley of springs|      north ward|    3083|  qld|     19120907|   4308555|  7| bbro|        7|
|    edward| denholm|           10|        corin place|           gold tyne|       clayfield|    4221|  vic|     19660306|   7119771|  9| eden|        9|
|   charlie|alderson|          266|hawkesbury crescent|deergarden caravn...|           cooma|    4128|  vic|     19440908|   1256748| 10| cald|       10|
|     molly|   roche|           59|willoughby crescent|        donna valley|         carrara|    4825|  nsw|     19200712|   1847058| 11| mroc|       11|
+----------+--------+-------------+-------------------+--------------------+----------------+--------+-----+-------------+----------+---+-----+---------+
```

The component column doesn't always increase in increments of 1 but seems to randomly skip numbers, I would like to make sure that the increase in increments of one as using this number to assign each person an id.
Does anybody know why Graphframes does this?

When I look further into this, for the approx 20,000 rows in my development dataframe approx 17% of entries have a skip in them. In extreme cases the gap can be up to around 20-30, i.e. one rows id is 5846 and the next one is 5868. My worry is, when I go scale in millions and hundreds of millions the gaps will get very large between id's which could create problems down the line.

TL;DR: Why does Sparks connected components seem to randomly skip values and not always increment by 1?

Answer (score 1):

Graphframes documentation never promises consecutive ids - instead the only guarantee it provides is:

> The resulting DataFrame contains all the vertex information and one additional column:
>
> component (LongType): unique ID for this component

In practice GraphX implementation uses the smallest ID in the component (["*return a graph with the vertex value containing the lowest vertex id in the connected component containing that vertex*"](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.graphx.lib.ConnectedComponents$)), and Graphframes [seems to do the same thing](https://github.com/graphframes/graphframes/blob/dc11c4a7c1b94cfe801f8480e6ea5c64064a8b99/src/main/scala/org/graphframes/lib/ConnectedComponents.scala#L222-L231).

Comment: What would be the best way to ensure consecutive id's?

Answer (score 0):

Like @user10802135 said, the component values are not guaranteed to be sequential.  If you want to make them sequential, you'll need to do some post-processing on the component field.  A pyspark solution to this would look something like this:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql import Window

# Define our window for partitioning data on - necessary for dense_rank() function
windowSpec = Window.partitionBy(F.lit(1)).orderBy('component')

# Redefine the component field, now in sequential order
df = df.withColumn('component', F.dense_rank().over(windowSpec))
```

By partitioning by the literal value of 1, all rows are considered in the `dense_rank()`, and ranking order is determined by the `.orderBy()` argument.  In this case the `.orderBy()` argument is set to `'component'`, which will order in ascending order by default.  The `.dense_rank()` functionality ensures that records under the same component will be given the same returned value, something that using `rank()` does NOT ensure.

There are some great examples and explanations of `.dense_rank()` and other window functions [here](https://sparkbyexamples.com/pyspark/pyspark-window-functions/).